# yii2-formwizard change model after select2 selection

Tags: yii2, yii2-formwizard

I'm trying to implement a multiple models form using the [form-wizard](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard) widget, with Profile as main model and few others as linked ones. When I select the entity type field for the main model, I would like to change the linked model for the next step, basing on the value of entity type field.
I have tried with this code:

```
Create Form Code


$modelUrlReletedModelsCreate = Profile::urlRelatedModelCreate();
$urlLinkedProfile = Url::to(['create']);

echo FormWizard::widget([
'formOptions'=>[
    'id'=>'profile_form',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'validationUrl' => Url::to(['profile-models-validation'])

],
'theme' => FormWizard::THEME_MATERIAL_V,
'steps' => [
    //step 1 
    [
        'model' => $model,
        'title' => \Yii::t('app', 'Profile'),
        'fieldConfig' => [
            'only' => ['entity_type_id', 'profile_type_id'], 
            'entity_type_id' => [
                'widget' => Select2::class,
                'options' => [
                    'data' => EntityType::arrayNamesList(),
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => \Yii::t('app','Select an element')],
                    'pluginEvents' => ['select2:select'=>'function(e){;'
                                            . 'var type = $("#pr-ty-sel").val();'
                                            . 'var profile= "'.($model->profile_id ? : "no").'";'
                                            . '$.ajax({ method: "GET",'
                                                    . 'url:"'.$urlLinkedProfile.'",'
                                                    . 'data:{ entity_text : e.params.data.text,'
                                                            . 'entity_id : e.params.data.id,'
                                                            . 'profile_type_id : type,'
                                                            . 'profile_id : profile},'
                                                    . 'success: function(data){'
                                                        . '$("#profile_form").html(data);'
                                                    . '}'
                                                  . '});}'],
                ],

            ],
            'profile_type_id' =>[
                'widget' => Select2::class,
                'options' => [
                    'data' => \app\models\ProfileType::arrayNamesList(),
                    'options' => ['placeholder' => \Yii::t('app','Select an element'),'id'=>'pr-ty-sel'],
                ],

            ]
        ],
        'description' => \Yii::t('app', 'Add Profile Type Data'),
        'formInfoText' => \Yii::t('app', 'Fill all fields'),
    ],

    //step 2 I want ot change here $linkedModel 
    [
        'model' => [$model,$linkedModel],
        'title' => \Yii::t('app', 'Personal Data'),
        'description' => \Yii::t('app', 'Insert Personal Data'),
    ],
]
]);

Controller Action Create Code

public function actionCreate($profileId = NULL)
{

    if($profileId AND $profileId !== 'no'){
        $model = $this->findModel($profileId);
    }else{
        $model = new Profile();
    }

    $profileLinkedModel = new ProfilePrivate();
    $renderMethod = 'render';
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $entityText = \Yii::$app->request->get('entity_text');
        $entity_id = \Yii::$app->request->get('entity_id');
        $profileTypeId = \Yii::$app->request->get('profile_type_id');
        $profileId = \Yii::$app->request->get('profile_id');

        //Utility function to clean the entity text (remove number and special characters)
        $entityTextCleaned = \app\components\Utility::cleanString($entityText);

        if ($entityTextCleaned == 'private') {
            $profileLinkedModel = new ProfilePrivate();
        } elseif ($entityText == 'company') {
            $profileLinkedModel = new ProfileCompany();
        } else {
            //@TODO 
            return FALSE;
        }

        $model->entity_type_id = $entity_id;
        $model->profile_type_id = $profileTypeId;


        $profileLinkedModel->profile_id = $model->profile_id;
        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

        $renderMethod = 'renderAjax';
    }

    //extra table field used to enable custom rule in model
    $model->createFullProfile = TRUE;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->profile_id]);
    }

    return $this->$renderMethod('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'profileLinkedModel' => $profileLinkedModel,
    ]);
}
```

When I select a field for entity type field, the server runs the ajax request on select event, but when it ends the other form field is not more selectable. So, in other words, after the ajax request I'm unable to select the profile type field. If I try to select the profile type field before the entity type field I can go to next step, but load always the default model.

Comment: not clear what you are asking , you have the `pluginEvent` defined for the `entity_type` and there is a typo on the first line `'select2:select' => 'function(e){;'` there should not be a `;` after `{` then you have the line `'$("#profile_form").html(data);` inside the success method which is the id of the `form` and means you are overriding the html of the complete form which isnt a sane thing to do , what are your requirements and what are you trying to do.

Comment: on the selection of any option in select2 what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry to be not clear. My purpose is change the linked model based on the selected value of entity type field. So, for instance, if I select 'Private' as entity type I will load the ProfilePrivate model as the linked one, if I choose 'Company' ProfileCompany will be loaded instead.  I tried to reload the form with the new linked model for the second step, based on entity type selected value, but it failed. However the `;` is part of the deleted line `console.log(e)` .

Comment: I have added the formwziard in a div with id `wizard-inner-form-registry`. The success callback function now push the data returned by ajax request `$("#wizard-inner-form-registry").html(data); `. Now the form seems to work . However, when I reach the final page and I click on the 'Finish' button I have the following javascript error: `TypeError: $.formwizard.fields[a][o] is undefined`. I don't know where this error came from.

Comment: what i am saying is that you cant change a modal via javascript or if you mean to say you want to override the form fields related to that model? ideally being the owner/developer of the widget i wont recommend doing what you are doing because the `forwizard.js` collects the field ids in the json array and need to be updated. the error you mentioned in the last message is somehow related to what i am saying, you might need to confirm by changing the source file in the `FormWizard` asset class for the javascript file `formwizard.min.js` to `formwizard.js`

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I resolved my issue removing the selection of the entity type and profile type fields from form wizard. I put them in another previous form. The controller checks the form data and, in base of the value of entity type, it will load the correct linked model for the form wizard.